# Select points within polygon mysql - No errors, no results-(What is wrong?)

Tags: mysql, gis

I've got a table in my MySQL database called property

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `property` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `latitude` double NOT NULL,
  `longitude` double NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 AUTO_INCREMENT ;

INSERT INTO `property` (`id`, `latitude`, `longitude`) VALUES
                       ( 1,   35.489623,   6.250875),
                       ( 2,   35.489341,   6.250135),
                       ( 3,   36.749996,   5.059664),
                       ( 4,   36.749996,   5.059664);
```

I've tried with those two queries below to view points within a polygon.
There is no error and no result, although two rows supposed to appear

```
SELECT id FROM `property` WHERE
ST_Contains( GeomFromText('POLYGON(35.49088 6.25108,35.48954 6.24853,35.48732 6.25164,35.48912 6.25381,35.49109 6.2525)'),
             POINT(property.latitude, property.longitude)
            )
```

And

```
SELECT id FROM `property` WHERE
ST_Contains( GeomFromText('POLYGON(35.49088 6.25108,35.48954 6.24853,35.48732 6.25164,35.48912 6.25381,35.49109 6.2525)'),
             GeomFromText( CONCAT( 'POINT(', property.latitude, ' ', property.longitude, ')' ) )
           )
```

I can't figure out why there no result.

ps: I've checked that the polygon completely contains two points (35.489623,   6.250875) and  (35.489341,   6.250135)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Theres 3 issues

Firsly `geomfromtext` is the wrong function. You should be using `PolygonFromText`

Secondly syntax, You need 2 brackets in the polygon function example

```
 select  PolygonFromText('POLYGON((35.49088 6.25108,35.48954 6.24853,35.48732 6.25164,35.48912 6.25381,35.49109 6.2525, 35.49088 6.25108))')
```

Thirly (This is also fixed above) You do not have a closed polygon, Your last point and first point should be equal

In your example the polygon code was returning `null` and breaking

Comment: Problem solved.
Thank you for your help.
since there is no a mysql documentation i spent All the day trying to spot the problem.

Comment: Accept the answer if it's helped :)

Comment: i am new in this site i tried to mark it as solved but i couldn't